# Twisted task.loop and pb auth

Tags: python, loops, twisted

Learn Twisted. I decided to write a server and client that once a second to share data.
Wrote one implementation, but it seems to me that it is not correct.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from twisted.spread import pb
from twisted.internet import reactor, task
from twisted.cred import credentials
from win32com.server import factory

class login_send:

    def __init__(self):
        self.count=0
        self.timeout = 1.0
        self.factory = pb.PBClientFactory()
        reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8800, self.factory)

    def testTimeout(self):
        self.count+=1
        print self.count

        def1 = self.factory.login(credentials.UsernamePassword("test1","bb1b"))
        def1.addCallbacks(self.good_connected, self.bad_connected)
        def1.addCallback(self.send_data)
        def1.addErrback(self.disconnect)
        if self.count>10:def1.addBoth(self.disconnect)

    def start(self):
        l = task.LoopingCall(self.testTimeout)
        l.start(self.timeout)
        reactor.run()

    def good_connected(self, perspective):
        print 'good login and password', perspective
        return perspective

    def bad_connected(self, perspective):
        print 'bad login or password', perspective
        return perspective

    def send_data(self, perspective):
        print 'send'
        return perspective.callRemote("foo", self.count)

    def disconnect(self, perspective):
        print 'disconnect'
        reactor.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    st=login_send()
    st.start()
```

Code: if login and password True -> send self.count, if login or password False -> disconnect, if self.count>10 -> disconnect

The first mistake, in my opinion is that I have to login every time.

```
def1 = self.factory.login(credentials.UsernamePassword("test1", "bb1b"))
```

How to make **one** authorization, and continue to send data every second?

simple test server code:

```
from zope.interface import implements

from twisted.spread import pb
from twisted.cred import checkers, portal
from twisted.internet import reactor

class MyPerspective(pb.Avatar):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def perspective_foo(self, arg):
        print "I am", self.name, "perspective_foo(",arg,") called on", self
        return arg

class MyRealm:
    implements(portal.IRealm)
    def requestAvatar(self, avatarId, mind, *interfaces):
        if pb.IPerspective not in interfaces:
            print 'qqqq'
            raise NotImplementedError
        return pb.IPerspective, MyPerspective(avatarId), lambda:None

p = portal.Portal(MyRealm())
c = checkers.InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse(test1="bbb",
                                                     user2="pass2")
p.registerChecker(c)
reactor.listenTCP(8800, pb.PBServerFactory(p))
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should do the trick.

```
# Upper case first letter of class name is good policy.
class Login_send:

    def __init__(self):
        # initialize the state variable to False.
        self.connection = False
        self.count=0
        self.timeout = 1.0
        self.factory = pb.PBClientFactory()
        reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8800, self.factory)

    def testTimeout(self):
        self.count+=1
        print self.count

        # no connection -- create one.
        if not self.connection:
            self.assign_connection()

        # cached connection exists, call send_data manually.
        elif self.count > 10:
            self.disconnect(self.connection)
        else:
            #you probably want to send data only if it it should be valid.
            self.send_data(self.connection)       

    def assign_connection(self):
    ''' Creates and stores a Deffered which represents the connection to
        the server. '''
        # cache the connection.
        self.connection = self.factory.login(
                              credentials.UsernamePassword("test1","bb1b"))
        # add connection callbacks as normal.
        self.connection.addCallbacks(
                              self.good_connected, self.bad_connected)
        self.connection.addCallback(self.send_data)
        self.connection.addErrback(self.disconnect)

    def disconnect(self, perspective):
        # be sure to cleanup after yourself!
        self.connection = False
        print 'disconnect'
        reactor.stop()

    # the rest of your class goes here.
```

Comment: When using your code and password is correct here, I get this error.    File "C:/Dropbox/my_py/test/client.py", line 72, in send_data
    return perspective.callRemote("foo", self.count)
exceptions.AttributeError: Deferred instance has no attribute 'callRemote'.  In the beginning, I also tried to write similar code, but received an error that could not fix. I add to post simple server.

Comment: @Echeg What about assigning self.connection in send_data?

Comment: May be make sense: self.send_data(self.connection) ->             self.connection.addCallback(self.send_data)
self.connection.addErrback(self.disconnect)  and change  def send_data -> print 'echo', perspective.callRemote("foo", self.count)
return perspective